# Will php reload file content from filesystem when opcache is enable and use 'require' keyword?

Tags: php, opcache

My application use `require` to load app routes, like this

```
require __DIR__ . '/Order.php';
```

And I have open `opcache` extension, configuration is

```
enable_cli=1
memory_consumption=128
interned_strings_buffer=8
max_accelerated_files=4000
revalidate_freq=60
fast_shutdown=1
opcache.save_comments=0
```

I want to know if php reload `__DIR__ . '/Order.php'` from filesystem every request, even if `opcache` is enable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to avoid it, use `require_once`

Comment: Even if using `opcache` ?